# make an embedded webpage fit the width and height of the browser window?

Tags: html, css, iframe, embed

I'm using this code to embed a page into my website at 1300x700 pixels

```
<iframe src="http://example.com"
    width="1300" height="700"></iframe>
```

Is there a way I can make it stretch or shrink to match the size of the browser window?
(preferably with -30px at the top for the navbar, currently have this set up with css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use percentages for width/height instead, and then use pixels to set the margin with the navbar

Comment: This works in some browsers, but the W3C maintains that the `width` and `height` attributes of an `embed` element must be "absolute value[s]; percentages are not allowed."
Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed